# pip install fails on docker build

Tags: python, docker, ssl

I am having a strange problem. I have following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.8

WORKDIR /app


RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash g++ postgresql-dev python3-dev
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
...
```

I'm building it with command `docker build -t mydocker .`. It builds fine on other computers but fails on mine with following error:

```
Certificate did not match expected hostname:pypi.org. Certificate:{  
   'subject':((('organizationalUnitName',
   'Domain Control Validated'   ),
   ),
   (('commonName',
   '.fireonskull.com'   ),
   )),
   'issuer':((('countryName',
   'US'   ),
   ),
   (('stateOrProvinceName',
   'Arizona'   ),
   ),
   (('localityName',
   'Scottsdale'   ),
   ),
   (('organizationName',
   'GoDaddy.com, Inc.'   ),
   ),
   (('organizationalUnitName',
   'http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/'   ),
   ),
   (('commonName',
   'Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2'   ),
   )),
   'version':3,
   'serialNumber':'4B1A6F1D6CB55CA2',
   'notBefore':'Aug 25 08:48:05 2018 GMT',
   'notAfter':'Aug 25 08:48:05 2019 GMT',
   'subjectAltName':(('DNS',
   '.fireonskull.com'   ),
   ('DNS',
   'fireonskull.com'   )),
   'OCSP':   ('http://ocsp.godaddy.com/',
   ),
   'caIssuers':   ('http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt',
   ),
   'crlDistributionPoints':   ('http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-860.crl',
   )
}Retrying (Retry(total=4,
connect=None,
read=None,
redirect=None,
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of '.fireonskull.com',
'fireonskull.com'",),)': /simple/pandas/  
Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('organizationalUnitName', 'Domain Control Validated'),), (('commonName', '.fireonskull.com'),)), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'US'),), (('stateOrProvinceName', 'Arizona'),), (('localityName', 'Scottsdale'),), (('organizationName', 'GoDaddy.com, Inc.'),), (('organizationalUnitName', 'http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/'),), (('commonName', 'Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '4B1A6F1D6CB55CA2', 'notBefore': 'Aug 25 08:48:05 2018 GMT', 'notAfter': 'Aug 25 08:48:05 2019 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '.fireonskull.com'), ('DNS', 'fireonskull.com')), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.godaddy.com/',), 'caIssuers': ('http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.godaddy.com/gdig2s1-860.crl',)} Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of '.fireonskull.com',
'fireonskull.com'",
),
)':/simple/pandas/
```

The error mentions the name `fireonskull.com`, which sounds familiar to me. I once had a SSL certificate for this domain on my computer.

But what does `docker build` has to do with files on my system. Also `pip install` works fine on the host OS. Please help!

Comment: How is your computer networked? Does it go though a proxy or anything? Maybe something is messing with your dns? hostsfiles etc? looks like your connection has gone somewhere it shouldn't have.

Comment: My network is normal broadband service. Also other computers on my network are able to build this docker without an error. Yes it looks like something wrong with dns or something similar but couldn't figure out what it is. I delete my hosts file and setup Goold DNS and its still the same. I will now try connecting with another network and let you know. Update: I connected with my perform hotspot network and got the same error, so its not a network issue.

Comment: @Lokesh Could you add the following code before the code installing packages from requirements.txt     **RUN pip3 --version**. older versions of pip have known issues with SSL verification. Put commands in Dockerfile to upgrade the pip3 to the latest version if it is not and then try again.

Comment: You can also try adding `RUN apk install dig && dig pypi.org` and compare the result to running it on a computer that's working. Maybe the IP address it tries to connect to will give you a hint as to what's messing with your network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dirty quickfix could be to define what dns the container should use in the build command:

```
docker build --dns=1.1.1.1 -t mydocker .
```

But that does of course not fix the root cause. @kichik is on to something in his comment above. You need to debug how the name is resolved. I would prefer to do that from an interactive shell.

```
docker run -ti openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.8 sh
```

First checkout what dns server is used:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

I get nameserver 192.168.65.1, which is the host machine

Now install bind-tools to get dig and query pypi.org

```
apk add bind-tools
dig pypi.org
```

That should give you an answer that's suppose to look like this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.12.3 <<>> pypi.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55237
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pypi.org.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pypi.org.       31  IN  A   151.101.64.223
pypi.org.       31  IN  A   151.101.0.223
pypi.org.       31  IN  A   151.101.192.223
pypi.org.       31  IN  A   151.101.128.223

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.65.1#53(192.168.65.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 26 08:25:29 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

Most likely your answer will show you that the dns doesn't resolve correctly. To get more info on how the domain is resolved use the +trace option for dig

```
dig +trace pypi.org
```

That should hopefully reveal what responds with the wrong address.

---

**This was my first answer, leaving it here for future reference**

Given that it works on your host OS, it sounds like you have a proxy setup in your docker configuration.

Open your docker preferences and go to the proxy tab to see.

[image: Docker proxy settings]

It could also be in your ~/.docker/config.json. Something like this:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

Comment: There's no proxy set in `~/.docker/config.json`. These are the contents of my `config.json` https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/0b8b9316352df3a3ccfe1c5739330288

Comment: Your dns fix worked for me. Many thanks, this had me blocked for days and I had to use another system everytime.

Answer (score 1):

From the thing I see, you have a problem with the SSL check/verification.
Try to add this in pip install step:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I tried that long ago. It didn't work. It gives error `No matching distribution found for pandas (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))`

Answer (score -4):

Given that you are running from an `openjdk` image, it does not have everything ptyhon needs, add this to your dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3.6 \
    python3-pip \
    && \
apt-get clean && \
```

Comment: `apt-get` doesn't work with alpine. Also I'm adding python package with `apk --no-cache python3-dev`. Thirdly its not a problem as python package and the docker builds on other computers except mine.